# Return to view from another function in laravel

Tags: laravel, function, store

Hi I'm saving information from blade. The form goes to store function. After saving data I have to send push info using GCM. But this function can not return to view. How can solve this?

```
  public function store(Request $request)
   {
    $request->validate([
        'title_uz' => 'required',        
        'desc_uz' => 'required',
        'url_uz' => 'required',
        'company_id' => 'required',
    ]);
      News::create($request->all());
      $this->versionUpdate();
      $this->sendpush($request);
     }
```

And next function

```
public function sendpush (Request $request)
{
    $fcmUrl = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $notification = [
        'title' => $request->title_uz,
        'text' => $request->desc_uz,
    ];

    ***** here is some functions *******

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $result_to = json_decode($result);

    if ($result_to === null) {
        return redirect()->route('news.index')
            ->with('success','DIQQAT!!! Yangilik qo`shildi ammo  push-xabar yuborilmadidi.');
    }
    else {
        return redirect()->route('news.index')
            ->with('success','Yangilik qo`shildi  va push-xabar muvoffaqiyatli yuborildi.');
    }
}
```

$result_to returns value but the browser holds at blank screen. It seems the store function holds at the end.

Comment: You are not returning anything at this line `$this->sendpush($request);`

Comment: you need to do in master function `return  $this->sendpush($request);` then it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this line `return $this->sendpush($request);`instead of this `$this->sendpush($request);`

Answer (score 0):

you have redirect from this method so you can try like these

```
$result_to = $this->sendpush($request);;
    if ($result_to === null) {
        return redirect()->route('news.index')
            ->with('success','DIQQAT!!! Yangilik qo`shildi ammo  push-xabar yuborilmadidi.');
    }
    else {
        return redirect()->route('news.index')
            ->with('success','Yangilik qo`shildi  va push-xabar muvoffaqiyatli yuborildi.');
    }
```